# C# generics - require interface method to return typeof(this)

Tags: .net, generics

I can implement a C# interface like this:

```
namespace SM.DTOs
{
    internal interface IMappable<T> where T : class
    {
        Expression<Func<T, IMappable<T>>> MapTo(T domainModel);
    }
}
```

but is it possible to specify that the IMappable returned by MapTo is of the same type as the class implementing IMappable. e.g. for the class

```
 public class PersonDto : IMappable<Person>
```

the result of the MapTo method should be a typeof(PersonDto)

an abstract class would be equally suitable. Thank you

Comment: You must add another generic type argument to your interface: `internal interface IMappable<T, TDto>`, and then the method: `Expression<Func<T, IDto>> MapTo(...)`.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - do oyu want to put it up as an answer and I'll accept it - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to add another generic type argument to your interface, specifying the type of the class that implements the interface.

Unfortunately there is no way to get hold of this type without something like that extra parameter, and there is even no way to ensure the writer of the class isn't lying.

But here's what you should do:

```
internal interface IMappable<T, TImplementer>
    where T : class
    where TImplementer : IMappable<T, TImplementer>
{
    Expression<Func<T, TImplementer>> MapTo(T domainModel);
}
```

And to implement it:

```
public class PersonDto : IMappable<Person, PersonDto>
```